# Custom Components for building 2D world

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Hi  I'm trying to make a game world which is built from 2D sprites.

For example (http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/Preview_97.png)

I first attempted to build a single house and after perfectly aligning about 30+ sprites I realized the scale of the task I have given myself.

I'm wondering is it possible to create a custom component where i can give it a public width/height and it will create a house out of small sprites both in the editor and when I play the game.

If it is can someone give me a simple example on how to go about this as I have never created custom editing tools in unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called "tile editor".

You can find many editors in Unity Asset Store.

Here is one of them named exactly "Tile Editor": https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/23091

If you do not want a paid one you can search for free version of that tools.